# Elasticsearch 7.x Search Idle Slow

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the Elasticsearch 7.x reference

> If `index.refresh_interval` is not set, shards that haven’t seen search traffic for at least index.search.idle.after seconds will not receive background refreshes until they receive a search request. Searches that hit an idle shard where a refresh is pending will wait for the next background refresh (within 1s).

I don't really sure about the pending behaviour. Will It wait for the refresh to begin or until finish. But the probelm I met is that the searches hit an idle are quite slow and make the  search performance of the system unstable.

If the designed behaviour is waiting for the refresh until fresh. Can it be modified that just trigger the fresh, but don't wait to make the idle search faster.

And another question is that if an idle shard recevies some data to index and will not receive any serach traffic for some times like hours. Will it just keep for waiting and not refresh the index.

Comment: By default `index.refresh_interval` is set to `1s` and that should solve these refresh issue. Why did you unset the refresh interval?

Comment: Yes ,the default value of `index.refresh_interval` is `1s`. I did not unset the refresh internal. But the reference said that  If this setting is not explicitly set(which is my situation，using the deafult), then shards the will bacame idle after `index.search.idle.after` seconds. I also confirm that if  explicitly set to `1s`，the shared will not become idle like you said.

Comment: If not explicitly set, then the value is the default one, i.e. 1s. Can you show what you get from `GET your-index-name/_settings?include_defaults=true` ?

Comment: The snippet clipped from the result 
`"allocation": {
          "max_retries": "5"
        },
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "indexing": {
          "slowlog": {
            "reformat": "true",
            "threshold": {
              "index": {
                "warn": "-1",
                "trace": "-1",
                "debug": "-1",
                "info": "-1"
              }
            },
            "source": "1000",
            "level": "TRACE"
          }
        },`

Comment: Ok, so your refresh interval is indeed set to 1s, unless it's because you just changed it during your testing

Comment: The result is from the index I just recreated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will It wait for the refresh to begin or until finish.

It will wait for the refresh to finish.

> Can it be modified that just trigger the fresh, but don't wait to make the idle search faster.

Yes, we can explicitly set index.refresh_interval to 1 second or sth else to opt out of the automatic disabling of background refreshes.  Another solution is to update the dynamic index setting index.search.idle.after from "30s" to a large value like "3600s".

> And another question is that if an idle shard recevies some data to index and will not receive any serach traffic for some times like hours. Will it just keep for waiting and not refresh the index.

Yes.

Comment: > It will wait for the refresh to finish.

What if the refresh takes seconds to finish? That's the problem. The docs says "wait for the next background refresh (within 1s)."  What does "within 1s" means? It will wait   up to 1s even if the refresh does not finish? "1s" is a fixed value or equals to refresh_interval?

Comment: If the refresh takes 2 secs to finish, the query will have to wait for 2 seconds. 1s is not fixed.